# Why insertion method skips the validation?

Tags: php, oop

I am trying to practice OOP on registering users, so i have started making validation and insertion. the problem is that when i call the validation function directly from the class it does the job normally, but when i call the insertion function which calls the validation, it seems that no validation occurs, but just skips to insertion.

```
    <?php
require_once('../dbconnection.php');
class USERS {
    const usersTable = TABLE_PREIX.'-users';
    public $username, $firstname, $lastname, $email, $password, $error,$_connection;
    public function __construct(){
        //Create DB connection
        $this->_connection= DB_CONN::getInstance()->getConnection();
    }

    //Set user
    public function setUSER($username, $email, $firstname = "", $lastname = ""){
        $this->username = $username;
        $this->email = $email;
        $this->firstname = $firstname;
        $this->lastname = $lastname;

        $this->validateUser($this->username,$this->email,$this->firstname,$this->lastname);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO xjk-users (username, email, firstname, lastname)
                VALUES ($this->username, $this->email, $this->firstname, $this->lastname)";

                if ($this->_connection->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                    header('Location: '.SITE_URL.'?message=user_inserted');
                    exit();
                } else {
                    $this->error[] = 'insert_user_error';
                    header('Location:'.SITE_URL.'?errors='.implode(',',$this->error));
                    exit();
                }

    }

    public function validateUser($username, $email, $firstname , $lastname ){
        if(empty($username) || empty($email)){
            return header('Location:'.SITE_URL.'?errors=empty_fields');
        }

        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            return header('Location:'.SITE_URL.'?errors=invalid_email');
        }
    }

}

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && isset($_POST['registration'])){
    $username = $_POST['register-username'];
    $email = $_POST['register-email'];
}
$user = new USERS();
$user->setUSER($username,$email);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`header` does not immediately stop the code. It just sets a header.

Your `validateUser` should return something, or you can use an exception model and have it throw on invalid input.

```
public function validateUser($username, $email, $firstname, $lastname) {
    if( empty($username) || empty($email)) {
        throw new BadFunctionCallException("Missing name/email");
    }
    if( !filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        throw new UnexpectedValueException("Invalid email");
    }
}
```

You can then use `try..catch` when calling this function to catch validation errors.

Alternatively, just have the function `return true;` or `return false;` based on the validity of the parameters.

All of this to say, you need to actually stop the insertion code from running when the input is invalid!

Comment: Nice value add with the exceptions

Answer (score 1):

When you call the method `validateUser()`, it has a return value, which is a header. When you call the method `setUSER()`, it calls the `validateUser()` method, but does nothing with the result. So, even if `validateUser()` is returning a header (and yes, that header will form part of the page response, that's how the PHP `header()` function works), it will still continue executing the remainder of the `setUser()` method as it has no indication that execution needs to break.

<strike>I'd suggest moving the block of code in `validateUser()` to be embedded inside the `setUSER()` method.</strike>

I'd suggest following Niet's advice to use Exceptions.

---

P.S. Props for getting interested in OOP. I don't think your code hits the nail on the head, but you need to get involved in order to learn how to properly harness OOP techniques. In your case, you would probably want a `User` object that represents the user, and a `UserService` that handles things like validating new user properties, and creating new users.

Comment: thank you, and yes i am sure i didn't implement every thing as it should be, and sure getting hands in will give me more.I will consider your advice, thank you